# How to save a json file using json.dump without the square bracket

Tags: python, json, pandas

I need to save the `json` file without the beginning and ending `[` and `]` respectively.

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['abc', 'pqr', 'xzy'],
                  'score' : [85, 90, 80],
                  'address' : ['ab street', 'pq street', 'xy ave']})

df
    name    score   address
0   abc 85  ab      street
1   pqr 90  pq      street
2   xzy 80  xy      ave
```

I then try to save the above dataframe using:

```
jl = json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records'))
f = open('expfile.json', 'w')
json.dump(jl, f, indent = 4)
f.close()
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "abc",
        "score": 85,
        "address": "ab street"
    },
    {
        "name": "pqr",
        "score": 90,
        "address": "pq street"
    },
    {
        "name": "xzy",
        "score": 80,
        "address": "xy ave"
    }
]
```

Which is fine enough, but I need the output without the starting and ending square brackets as below:

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "score": 85,
    "address": "ab street"
},
{
    "name": "pqr",
    "score": 90,
    "address": "pq street"
},
{
    "name": "xzy",
    "score": 80,
    "address": "xy ave"
}
```

Could someone please let me know how to accomplish the same.
PS I have complex nested dictionary/json structures inside my columns in many of my dataframes, I parsed them using `ast.literal_eval`.

I tried using `to_json(orient = 'records', lines = True)` to which I got this error `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 425)`.

Comment: That's not a JSON file any more, so JSON writers will unlikely generate it directly. You could achieve it either via string manipulation (removing those lines, and "unindent" everything else between by one level), or via looping over `jl` yourself and JSON-ing the elements one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jsoning-in-a-loop variant would be something like this:

```
jl = [
    {
        "name": "abc",
        "score": 85,
        "address": "ab street"
    },
    {
        "name": "pqr",
        "score": 90,
        "address": "pq street"
    },
    {
        "name": "xzy",
        "score": 80,
        "address": "xy ave"
    }
]

import json
print(",\n".join(json.dumps(x, indent=4) for x in jl))
```

Produces

> ```
> {                                                                     
>     "name": "abc",                                                        
>     "score": 85,                                                          
>     "address": "ab street"                                                
> },                                                                    
> {                                                                     
>     "name": "pqr",                                                        
>     "score": 90,                                                          
>     "address": "pq street"                                                
> },                                                                    
> {                                                                     
>     "name": "xzy",                                                        
>     "score": 80,                                                          
>     "address": "xy ave"                                                   
> }
> ```

Comment: How to I write it back as a `JSON` file to file directory?

Comment: was about to post the same answer, this is the way. To go from a dataframe to this, just cast your dataframe to a list of dicts: `print(",\n".join(json.dumps(x, indent=4) for x in df.to_dict(orient="records")))`

Comment: The `",\n".join(json.dumps(x, indent=4) for x in jl)` part is a simple string, you can write it into a file. @KarthikS

Comment: I get output like : `"{\n    \"name\": \"abc\",\n    \"score\": 85,\n    \"address\": \"ab street\"\n},\n{\n    \"name\": \"pqr\",\n    \"score\": 90,\n    \"address\": \"pq street\"\n},\n{\n    \"name\": \"xzy\",\n    \"score\": 80,\n    \"address\": \"xy ave\"\n}"` after I do `json.dump(jl1, f, indent = 4)` on the `jl1 = ",\n".join(json.dumps(x, indent=4) for x in jl)` step

Comment: you just need to write the string, don't do another `json.dump`: `f = open('yourfile.txt', 'w'); f.write(jl1); f.close()`

Comment: I am trying to understand your code for learning, When I try `print(", \n".join(json.dumps({'name': 'abc', 'score': 85, 'address': 'ab street'}, indent=4)))` I don't get the expected result of `{
    "name": "abc",
    "score": 85,
    "address": "ab street"
}`
Could you please let me know where am I going wrong with my understanding of your code

Comment: `join()` needs an iterable of strings, like a list. Try writing something like `"*".join(["a","b","c"])` to see its operation in its simplest form.

Answer (score 0):

If want to drop the []'s in output then can iterate over the rows in the dataframe and write out a record at a time.

```python
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['abc', 'pqr', 'xzy'],
                  'score' : [85, 90, 80],
                  'address' : ['ab street', 'pq street', 'xy ave']})

with open("out.dat", "w") as fout:
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if idx != 0:
            fout.write(',\n')
        fout.write(json.dumps(row.to_dict(), indent=4))
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "score": 85,
    "address": "ab street"
},
{
    "name": "pqr",
    "score": 90,
    "address": "pq street"
},
{
    "name": "xzy",
    "score": 80,
    "address": "xy ave"
}
```